# Several tabs (TabHost) in one activity android

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm working in a chat app. So, the design the user asks me is `"2 groups"` of tabs. One has Rooms and Private chats, and the other `"List of users"` and `"List of rooms"`. How is it possible? I tried with:

```
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

and:

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost_othertabs"
```

but gives me the error:

Could not create Tab content because could not find view with id

Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/ for tabs sample where you can work out with tabs.
But it is not recommended to use tabs as it is deprecated instead use fragments like at http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/.